# LINQ: Combine 2 groups

Tags: c#, linq

Here's the table, lets call it `temp table`:

```
ID    Type   tb1Id    tb2Id      Detail
1     tb1    a        null       Detail of 1
2     tb2    null     b          Detail of 2
3     tb1    a        null       Detail of 3
4     tb2    null     b          Detail of 4
```

Now this `a` and `b` is a foreign key to 2 different tables.

I would like to group this table.

Tried this:

```
var list1 = db.Temp.Where(x=> x.tb1Id != null).GroupBy(x=> x.tb1.SomeOtherId);
var list2 = db.Temp.Where(x=> x.tb2Id != null).GroupBy(x=> x.tb2.SomeOtherId);
var final = list1.Union(list2); <-- This doesn't work
```

**Note:** `SomeOtherId` is not the primary key of `tb1` and `tb2` which is referred to in `temp table`

Comment: You might need an intermediate class for that.. having so called common `Id` rather than in the two different columns.. so that the results for `list1` and `list2` can be combined under the same `CommonClass` with `Id` as keys for the `Group`

Comment: What about just doing `db.Temp.GroupBy(x => x.tb1.SomeOtherId ?? x.tb2.SomeOtherId)`?

Comment: What error are you getting?  What are the types of list1 and list2?

Comment: @juharr Thanks for the idea. I just changed the code to `db.Temp.GroupBy(x=> x.tb1 != null ? x.tb1.SomeOtherId : x.tb2.SomeOtherId)` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with anonymous types.

```
var reclassified = db.Temp
       .Where(item => item.tb1Id != null || item.tb2Id != null)
       .Select(item => 
          new 
          { 
                data = item, 
                FK = (item.tb1ID != null) ? 
                      item.tb1.SomeOtherId : 
                      item.tb2.SomeOtherId
               }
          );
```

After you run  this query you will have all of your objects with the id. Then you should be able to accomplish the same thing you wanted to do with it grouped. Note the actual data is then stored in the anonymous as "data" and you have a new property/column, "FK", for the "SomeOtherId"

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Temp.GroupBy(x => x.tb1Id ?? x.tb2Id);
```